# using scope on an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

So I got this crazy idea that I wanted to apply a scope to an included association.  This is what I figured out, and it seems to work just fine:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :races
  has_many :bad_races, :conditions => Race.bad_medals_sql, :class_name => "Race"
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.bad_medals_sql
    arel_table[:prizes].eq('medals').to_sql
    # This returns a string
    # "`races`.`prizes` = 'medals'"
  end

  def self.bad_medals
    where(bad_medals_sql)
  end
end

Event.includes(:bad_races)
Reloading...
  Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`
  Race Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `races`.* FROM `races` WHERE (`races`.event_id IN (1,2,3,4) AND (`races`.`prizes` = 'medals'))
```

The problem is that it's really obtuse.  In order to have the scope defined on Race (to use elsewhere) and to use it on the Event's association I have to have two methods on Race.  For each scope.

I'm sure that I could wrap the pattern into a plugin or some such, but I'd much rather use native AR/ARel if that's possible.  Any ideas for doing that?

Comment: not to dig up dead posts, but you don't have to call `to_sql` on Arel, and infact shouldn't; just use it directly in the where condition

Answer (score 7):

This code seems overly complex. Assuming that your goal is to get all the events that contain races with only "medals" for prizes, wouldn't a simple `scope` work?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :races
  scope :bad_races, includes(:races).where("races.prizes=?", "medals")
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Then you can just run `Event.bad_races` to get the bad races.

Comment: "So I got this crazy idea that I wanted to apply a scope to an included association."

Comment: AFAIK you can DRY this code by making `bad` a scope in `Race`, and then just say `races.bad`. Or maybe it only works with scopes, I haven't checked :(

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko But in this case, he wants the events that had races meeting the conditions (i.e. he doesn't just want the Race objects, he wants the Event objects they belong to).

Answer (score 2):

You can use scopes on both models with [merge](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) method. It's really handy in this case:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :races
  scope :bad_races, -> { joins(:races).merge(Race.bad_medals) }
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  scope :bad_medals, -> { where(price: 'medal') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A more up to date way to express the scope of your association is the following:

```
scope :bad_races, -> { joins(:races).where(races: { prizes: 'medals' }) }
```